# Why "display: none !important" doesn't work here?

Tags: reactjs, less, display

The stylesheet is really simple so I don't know what could mess around the result.  I checked the style in the "elements".  It seems that I cannot overwrite "display: block" in user agent stylesheet even though I used "!important".

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.less";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="hide">Hello CodeSandbox</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

stylesheet

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  .hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

link with the environment:
[image: Edit 4zn1xn0269]

I expect "Hello CodeSandbox" to disappear.

Comment: Your rules are not applied at all. Otherwise the text would be at least centered. I don't know enough about less or codesandbox to say what the problem here is, but it's not with React itself or the CSS rules.

Comment: So do you think it's the problem of CodeSandbox?

Comment: Maybe. Or with the bundler. Or with the fact that you cannot import stylesheets just like this (maybe). I mean, the browser must either get a `style` element or a `link` element or something must set inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

Create react app 2(CRA2) supports SASS out of the box.
I assume that officially the CRA2 does not support the LESS. So if you needs exactly LESS you can use [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired). This package rewrites webpack configuration without ejecting.

Answer (score 0):

None of your styles get applied, and this is because the default codesandbox template (I guess, based on Create React App) does not support less.

It is a bit misleading, because it does not throw an error, but what it does is actually import the file as plain text, without setting it as style.

Two ways to see this, is that you can important the actual text:

```
import less_text from './styles.less';

console.log('less_text:', less_text);
```

Which will logs the contexts of the less file, without transpilation even.
What you could do for now, as I don't know how to use a template that supports less, is to change it to css for now. If you move `.hide { ... }` to the root of the css file, and import it as `import 'styles.css'` your styles do get applied :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are missing less processor. By default browser does not understand less and if you use webpsck then you need loader for it

Answer (score 0):

You need a less loader. Something like this https://medium.com/@joseph0crick/react-css-modules-less-webpack-4-a50d902d0a3